# How do I convert an aware datetime to a POSIX timestamp?

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, pytz

I'd like to specify 12 PM on a particular date in the central timezone and adjust for daylight savings time (CDT). I'd then like to convert this to a POSIX timestamp.

The first thing I reached for is:

```
d = datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 27, 12, tzinfo=???)
```

But I don't have a concrete CDT class. `pytz` does however:

```
z = pytz.timezone('EST5EDT')
d = datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 27, 12, tzinfo=z)
```

But this does not work (pytz documentation says as much but I don't understand why the constructor cannot use the timezone information). If I use November (fall back) or June (spring forward) I get still get `12:00:00-05:00` as the time portion.

Even if this did work the method to convert to a POSIX timestamp assumes a naive datetime:

```
posix = time.mktime(d.timetuple())
```

This timestamp represents 12PM in my local time zone.

Then there is `normalize()` with code and examples that I find very difficult to follow:

```
au_dt = au_tz.normalize(utc_dt.astimezone(au_tz))
```

I also tried to subtract my aware time from an epoch defined at January 1, 1970 but that doesn't work unless the datetime gets the UTC offset correct (see my second point above).

Can anyone help me with a mental model of how this stuff works in general and a solution to this problem in particular?

Comment: Sorry. I used Eastern Time in my example.

Answer (score 0):

This solution seems to work:

```
import pytz
import datetime

# Naive datetime (no timezone).
d = datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 27, 12)

cdt = pytz.timezone('US/Central')

# Give it a central time zone context.
d = cdt.localize(d)

# Determine the time in UTC.
d = d.astimezone(pytz.utc)

# Create a naive POSIX epoch.
epoch = datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)

# Give it context in the UTC time zone.
epoch = pytz.utc.localize(epoch)

# Number of seconds have elapsed since the epoch.
print (d - epoch).total_seconds()
```